# SharePoint 2010 - Filter View Based On Field Related to User

Tags: list, filter, sharepoint-2010

My list is a simple employee list, which contains basic information you'd expect(e.g. - Last Name, First Name, empID, Worksite, etc.). Is it possible to to filter a view to show records that are related to the current user's site?

Like... [Me].[Worksite]?

Please bear in mind installing add-ons or other 3rd-party extensions are restricted.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a one calculated columne which will have a condition on WorkSite column.

For example, [WorkSite] == [Me].[WorkSite].

This will set Yes or No for in that column.

Then generate a view which will filter the records where Calculated column has a value true.

In that way only those rows will be displayed which has the WorkSite as current user.